# "java -cp abc.jar xyz.Main" command on console in WinSCP gives error

Tags: console, winscp

"java -cp abc.jar xyz.Main" command on console in WinSCP gives error 
"unable to fetch console" itself, tries for multiple times and exits with maximum attempts are done.

Answer (score 0):

Your Java program requires probably interactive terminal (TTY).

[WinSCP console window](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_console) does not implement an interactive terminal.

See [section about limitations of executing commands in WinSCP](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/remote_command#limitations).

---

You have to use SSH terminal client that implements full terminal, like [PuTTY](https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/). You can actually [execute PuTTY from WinSCP itself](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/integration_putty#open_putty).